# Vim clears system clipboard on start

Tags: vim, clipboard, x11

I am using Vim 7.4.430 with `+clipboard` and `+xterm_clipboard` options on Ubuntu 14.04.1. When I start Vim with an empty `.vimrc` file, I can use `"+p` to paste text from system clipboard. I can, as well, call `set clipboard^=unnamedplus` in a running Vim instance and directly paste from system clipboard with only `p`.

However if I start with a `.vimrc` file that contains **only** the `set clipboard^=unnamedplus`, pressing `p` will give `Nothing in register +` error. And, actually I lose whatever text I have in the system clipboard.

This happens both in terminal vim and in vim gui.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have introduced that bug with 7.4.396 and has been fixed with [patch 7.4.445](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/vim_dev/3yD_qZR4MdI/pwV0ndSpvpgJ)